# How to rename/refactor a whole libgdx/java project in eclipse

Tags: java, libgdx, refactoring, rename

Ive made a game with the libgdx framework in eclipse and I want to copy this project in the same workspace so I can make changes to this whilst viewing the original code.
I have tried refactoring before but it all messed up somehow and I ended up having to start a new project and copying over every class ( took a while )

Is there a way to rename the projects in a better way or  how do you rename them properly as I obviously did something wrong.

Answer (score 4):

In package explorer

1. Right click on project
2. Click Refactor > Rename or press Alt+Shift+R
3. Give new name